# Is it possible for Apache to mod_rewrite a file to its absolute path?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

### Question

Is it possible to re-write a symlinked document root to its resolved absolute path?

In other words, let's assume I have the following directory structure:

```
/www/current -> /www/tags/a
/www/tags/a
/www/tags/b
```

So /www/current is a symlink that points to /www/tags/a.

If /www/current is my document root, is it possible to re-write the file path to /www/tags/a, so that the file being served is no longer following a symlink, but serving the file at the full absolute path?  Note that I am **NOT asking about FollowSymLinks**.  I want to actually re-write the served file to the full absolute path.

---

### Background Info

So you may be asking, why do I care about this?

Well, there appears to be an issue with symlinked paths when serving PHP content.  If you use a symlink as part of your deploy process, and flip it at the exact wrong time, it appears that Apache will actually read the previous file, and yet PHP will instantiate magic constants such as __FILE__ with the resolved new directory.

So in my previous example, this race condition would play out as follows:

1) Apache receives a request for /www/current/myfile.php
2) Apache/mod_php reads the file /www/tags/a/myfile.php
3) Symlink gets flipped to /www/current -> /www/tags/b
4) PHP now interprets and executes the code.  It looks up the file directory and resolves __FILE__ to /www/tags/b, which is the **wrong file**.

This leads to all sorts of havoc, because now new code will start including files from previous deploys.

I'm aware that the folks at Etsy have [written a module that seems designed to solve this very problem](http://codeascraft.com/2013/07/01/atomic-deploys-at-etsy/), but I'm wondering if the same can be accomplished through existing apache modules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache redirects based on symlinks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351271/apache-redirects-based-on-symlinks)

Comment: Interesting!  I think parts of the answer to that question actually do apply to this.  The actual questions are quite different though.  I do not want to redirect the URL as that question is asking, but re-write the document path internally to the absolute path.